# Docker installation failed

Tags: docker

While installing Docker I'm getting this error.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/lib/apt/methods$ sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
FATA[0000] Error: 404 page not found
```

Looking for any suggestions?

Comment: That looks like maybe docker was having problems contacting the docker registry to download the `ubuntu` image.  Maybe it was a transient problem?  Are you still seeing the same behavior?

Comment: It's a rubbish error message though.

Comment: Any luck finding a work around for this issue?

Comment: Due to proxy connection in my work environment  I faced that error.Without proxy internet connection it works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by setting the proxy in /etc/default/docker.

I also had to unset the proxy in the environment variables :

`unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy`